# Increasing the reference count of a SKB

Tags: network-programming, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is there any simple way I can increase the reference count of SKB buffer in linux kernel so that the hardware wont free it.

I know that using skb_clone the reference count is automatically increased but I would like to know without creating a clone how can I increase the SKB reference count.

My purpose is to send the same packet multiple times and I dont want to do a skb_clone every time for this operation as I want to reuse the same memory.

Sample code I am using to the same SKB is as shown below

```
  for (i=0;i<=100;i++)
  {
    tmp_skb = skb_get(skb);
    if (tmp_skb == NULL)
    {
      printk ("Clone Failed");
      continue;
    }

    if ( (err = dev_queue_xmit(tmp_skb)) != NETDEV_TX_OK) {
      if(unlikely(enable_error))
        printk("ERROR - DEV QUEUE FAILED %d\n", err);

      err = -ENETDOWN; /* Probably we need a better error here */
      continue;
    }

    if (i==100)
    {
     printk("Loop is done\n");
     kfree_skb(skb);
     return(len);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What kernel version and what underlying hardware network driver do use use?

Comment: I am using 3.4.10 kernel version and the nic card is a intel gigabit nic card

Comment: Adding a clone really slows down the whole setup ... As my purpose is to send the packets at faster rate.

Comment: I'll suggest you to 1) skb_get 2) hexdump whole the skb 3) xmit an skb 4) hexdump whole the skb 5) compare 2 and 4 skb dumps

Comment: I will try the same .. but I have a doubt since a loop of 'n' might create an issue as the module will be using more CPU right ?? is it any how related to kernel hang ?

Comment: Sure, that loop consumes cpu time. You can call the `schedule` to avoid this. As of kernel hang I can't say anything as there is no any information (panic or any other dump). Maybe `netconsole` helps to get that ones?

Comment: Let me see how to use netconsole I never tried it before.

Comment: http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt

Comment: I guess netconsole will not be of great use for me since the moment kernel hangs the connection to the system is lost.

Comment: yeah but when the kernel freezes the whole system is unaccessable even the NIC cards hence I dont think UDP doesnt make any in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `get` an skb via the [skb_get](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/skbuff.h#L765) method:

```
758 /**
759  *      skb_get - reference buffer
760  *      @skb: buffer to reference
761  *
762  *      Makes another reference to a socket buffer and returns a pointer
763  *      to the buffer.
764  */
765 static inline struct sk_buff *skb_get(struct sk_buff *skb)
766 {
767         atomic_inc(&skb->users);
768         return skb;
769 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply llya .. A small doubt. I want to send the same SKB multiple times initially tried skb_clone but seems its slow. So can I use skb_get in a for loop to send the same packet n times ??

Comment: What method do you use to send an `skb`?

Comment: I am using dev_queue_xmit to send the skb. But are there different functions to transmit an skb ? Actually whenever the sendmsg is called I am trying to send the same skb 'n' number of times. When I am sending 10 pkts from userspace it is working fine but when I try to send 100 packets whole system hangs

Comment: It seems that `dev_queue_xmit` do something with the packet. It may pull the header or so on... You'll need to look `dev_queue_xmit` and at driver level callbacks, espesially `ndo_start_xmit`. So,  I think that clonning is a only one valid method.

Comment: Hmm thats bad then. I don't think dev_queue_xmit modifies the SKB it might pull the data but not change the SKB structure passed to it. In a simple experiment I tried from userspace I am sending a single pkt and in kernel space I am sending the same SKB 10 times and it worked fine. But when I try to send more packets from userspace it hangs

Comment: Seems we can use the chat option to discuss on it - if not if u can provide mail id i can mail